# Heroku - downloaded files are taking over 30 seconds to process with AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, heroku, amazon-s3

So I am using AWS as a cloud on my website. his main purpose is to be a storage unit (`s3`) everything works great until I have a large file(5mb or 7mb) that passes Heroku's 30 seconds time limit and sends a `H12` error.

```
s3.Object(BUCKET, file_full_name).put(Body=file_to_put)
```

the problem starts there. here I am writing the file to the cloud. and because it takes to long to write it the site continues to try and load the file and never does. `file_to_put` is byte type. How can I fix it so I could upload larger files to the cloud?

> Note I am need to read the file but first I need to fix this
>   problem

backend framework - flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where `worker` process types and Task queues come in (So you can use Celery+Redis with Flask or something similar).

Basically, you queue up the task of writing the file in a Task Queue (say Redis) and your `web` process returns 200 OK to the website visitor immediately. In the meantime your `worker` process picks the task from the queue and starts performing the time taking task (writing the file to S3).

On the front-end, you'll have to ask the visitor to "Come back after some time" or show a wait "spinner" or something that indicates to the visitor that file is not available yet. Once the file is written, you can send a signal to refresh the page, or maybe you can use JavaScript on the web page to check if the file is ready say every second, or simply ask the visitor to refresh the page after say a minute.

I know all this might sound complicated, but this is the way it is done. Your `web` process shouldn't be waiting on long running tasks.

Comment: I am already using redis but how would redis help this process? I need to write a binary file to AWS. do I need to save the file in a redis variable and use it?

Comment: Redis can be used for variety of ways. One is for caching, which you probably are doing, another is as a task queue or also called a message broker. You don't save the file in Redis, only an item in the queue that this task is to be done, then Celery picks the task. Too much to explain here, you'll have to follow some tutorial. This looks beginner friendly: https://medium.com/@frassetto.stefano/flask-celery-howto-d106958a15fe

Comment: So I did send the file in celery but it didn't return 200 OK immediately do I need to return the code the writes the file to AWS or just doing it in the celery function works to

Comment: Sent the file in Celery? And celery doesn't return a 200 OK. Can't understand the question. You got to get the basic idea about Celery right first. You'll find plenty of tutorials online. It's not that complex. As for the last part of your question, yeah, most probably your current function can be used as is with Celery.

Comment: I did get the idea and even used it in code. Can you see my recent questions and help me there please? No one is.